# How can I change the icon used by javapackager for .pkg installers?

Tags: macos, javapackager

Using `javapackager` under Mac OS X 10.12, I can generate a `.pkg` file. This package, when opened, contains a generic gray-colored icon, as shown in the image below:

[image]

How can I change the generic icon to one of my own choosing? I am currently using the option `-Bicon=....` to set an icon, which works for the application icon but does not appear to change the icon in the .pkg file. There do not appear to be any other icon-related options documented in [Oracle's documentation for `javapackager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you create a folder structure `package/macosx` and put a `.png` file inside that folder with the naming-convention `MyAppName-background.png` (replace `MyAppName` with your app name) the javapackager will pick it up. You can also put a `.icns` file `MyAppName.icns` in that same folder and it will be used for the application icon and in `dmg`-packaging if you would like to you use that too.